# UPnP control point with ruby

Tags: streaming, media-server, audio-playback, ruby

I get this error - `RuntimeError: eventmachine not initialized: evma_connect_to_server`
RPi3 with `gmediarender-resurrect`

Using this [library](https://github.com/sidoh/easy_upnp) and following the basic instructions

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'easy_upnp'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 
irb(main):003:0* searcher = EasyUpnp::SsdpSearcher.new 
=> #<EasyUpnp::SsdpSearcher:0x14ecbf0 @options={:timeout=>2, :mx=>1, :repeat_queries=>1}>
irb(main):004:0> devices = searcher.search 'ssdp:all'
=> [#<EasyUpnp::UpnpDevice:0x1374450 @uuid="uuid:644acae08213ec4b4ef81c9384e2df7a", @service_definitions=[{:location=>"http://192.168.1.6:49494/description.xml", :st=>"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"}, {:location=>"http://192.168.1.6:49494/description.xml", :st=>"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1"}, {:location=>"http://192.168.1.6:49494/description.xml", :st=>"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"}]>]
irb(main):005:0> device = devices.first
=> #<EasyUpnp::UpnpDevice:0x1374450 @uuid="uuid:644acae08213ec4b4ef81c9384e2df7a", @service_definitions=[{:location=>"http://192.168.1.6:49494/description.xml", :st=>"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"}, {:location=>"http://192.168.1.6:49494/description.xml", :st=>"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1"}, {:location=>"http://192.168.1.6:49494/description.xml", :st=>"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"}]>
irb(main):006:0> device.all_services
=> ["urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1", "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1", "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"]
irb(main):007:0> service = device.service 'urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1'
=> #<EasyUpnp::DeviceControlPoint:0x19e07c8 @urn="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1", @service_endpoint="http://192.168.1.6:49494/upnp/control/rendertransport1", @definition="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\.......
...
...
irb(main):008:0> 
irb(main):009:0>service.service_methods
=> [:GetCurrentTransportActions, :GetDeviceCapabilities, :GetMediaInfo, :GetPositionInfo, :GetTransportInfo, :GetTransportSettings, :Pause, :Play, :Seek, :SetAVTransportURI, :Stop, :SetNextAVTransportURI]
irb(main):012:0> service.Pause
RuntimeError: eventmachine not initialized: evma_connect_to_server
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:677:in `connect_server'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:677:in `bind_connect'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/em-http-request-1.1.5/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:55:in `activate_connection'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/em-http-request-1.1.5/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:92:in `setup_request'
    from (eval):6:in `post'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi/adapter/em_http.rb:50:in `block in request'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi/adapter/em_http.rb:68:in `_request'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi/adapter/em_http.rb:50:in `request'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi.rb:161:in `request'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi.rb:133:in `post'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:94:in `block in call_with_logging'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/request_logger.rb:12:in `log'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:94:in `call_with_logging'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:54:in `call'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/easy_upnp-1.1.11/lib/easy_upnp/control_point/client_wrapper.rb:54:in `call'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/easy_upnp-1.1.11/lib/easy_upnp/control_point/service_method.rb:31:in `call_method'
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/easy_upnp-1.1.11/lib/easy_upnp/control_point/device_control_point.rb:205:in `block in define_service_method'
    from (irb):12
    from /home/pi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'irb(main):013:0> ^C
```

Aim is to control music playback *(play,pause, vol up/down)* from Pi terminal while audio is streamed from Android to the Pi itself.

Can't understand what the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.
`HTTPI.adapter = :net_http`
This should be the adapter by default instead of Eventmachine.

And don't forget the arguments to pass for services, `service.Pause(InstanceID: 0)`